# Need to bounce an icon/button without jQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a form with save and reset buttons. And I have a button icon on the top of the form. I am trying to make the button icon bounce when a user clicks the save button. I don't want to use the jQuery UI. I already gave it a try but I just want to use the plain CSS and a simple onclick javascript function to make this work.

Here is the bounce CSS I am using:

```
 .bounce{
    position: relative;
    -webkit-animation: bounce 1s 5;
}

@-webkit-keyframes bounce{
    0%{
        bottom:5px;
    }
    25%, 75%{
        bottom: 15px;
    }

    50%{
        bottom: 20px;
    }
    100%{
        bottom: 0;
    }
}
```

The Css works pretty well, but obviously it bounces when the page is loaded as I have added the class="bounce" to the button icon.

```
<button class="container-list bounce" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#container-modal"><img src="images/container-rack.png"></button>
```

I have a very long form, and at the end, I have the button container as following which has the save and reset buttons.

```
 <div class="container-buttons">
      <button class="btn btn-success" id="save_container" type="submit">Save</button>
   <button class="btn btn-warning" type="reset">Reset</button>
     </div>
```

So, how can I trigger the bounce css property, whenever the save button is clicked? Please help me. :)

Comment: Add the class when the button is clicked?

Comment: Yes, but if I add the class, when the user clicks on the save button the 2nd time, the bounce effect wont occur right?

Comment: Don't add the class, but toggle the class when the button is clicked.

Comment: I used jQuery UI bounce function and I like it. Its really easy to use it. But it is entirely messing my CSS.

Comment: There are thousands of examples of this: https://www.google.ca/search?q=css+bounce&oq=css+bounce&aqs=chrome..69i57.1068j0j7&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8

Comment: Sorry, `.toggleClass()` won't work here! I have changed my answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to add the class when the button is clicked. By removing the class after 1 second (or however long your animation is), you can add it again with the same button.

Now, I don't see your jQuery or anything, so I'm just going to put some generic jQuery here:

```
$('#save_container').click(function () {
  var b = $('.container-list');
  b.addClass('bounce');
  setTimeout(function () {
      b.removeClass('bounce');;
  }, 1000);
});
```

When the `#save_container` is clicked, `.container-list` will get the class `.bounce` and remove it after 1 second (since my animation in the fiddle is 1 second long).

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/1Lmps5m5/)

**Answer 2**

As per Anthony Grist's suggestion, you could flip the operations around and with that get it to work with every single click.

That solution can be found in [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q355n4v2/1/) and the jQuery looks like this:

```
$('#save_container').click(function (e) {
    var b = $('button.container-list');
    b.removeClass('bounce');
    window.setTimeout(function() {
        b.addClass('bounce');
    }, 1);
});
```

In this code, the `.bounce` class gets removed and 1ms after that it gets added again. In the 2nd fiddle `$('.container-list')` contains `button` as well, but that's only because the HTML is a bit different.

The reason why you should go for answer two is that it can be triggered over and over again, without you having to wait for the class to be removed first.

Credit for answer 2 goes to @AnthonyGrist!

Comment: How is this any different to just calling `.toggleClass()` (which doesn't work, only every other click would result in the bounce)?

Comment: Oh wait, I forgot a piece!

Comment: @AnthonyGrist Completely changed it again. it's not the prettiest, but it's a solution :)

Comment: You could switch the order of operations around, and use a very tiny delay, like so: http://jsfiddle.net/q355n4v2/1/ That way every single click will work (though restart the animation).

Comment: @AnthonyGrist That's fantastic. That's what I was actually thinking to do and it works like magic. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @AnthonyGrist If you could add that fiddle as the separate Answer, I could check it as correct solution for this thread. :)

Comment: @ShellZero I have added it to my answer with credit to Anthony for coming up with the switch of operations :)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `.button` class from the element and add it on when the user clicks the button:

```js
var button = document.querySelector("button");
button.onclick = function() {
  var secondButton = document.querySelector("#second-button");
  secondButton.classList.remove("bounce");
  secondButton.offsetWidth = secondButton .offsetWidth;
  secondButton.classList.add("bounce");
};
```

```css
 .bounce {
   position: relative;
   -webkit-animation: bounce 1s 5;
 }
 @-webkit-keyframes bounce {
   0% {
     bottom: 5px;
   }
   25%,
   75% {
     bottom: 15px;
   }
   50% {
     bottom: 20px;
   }
   100% {
     bottom: 0;
   }
 }
```

```html
<button>Click Me!</button>
<button id="second-button">Now Click Me!</button>
```

<strike>You'll notice that if you press the button more than once the animation will not repeat. To work around this, use one of the techniques in this [article](https://css-tricks.com/restart-css-animation/):</strike>

```
var button = document.querySelector("button");
var secondButton = document.querySelector("#second-button")
button.onclick = function() {
  secondButton.classList.remove("bounce");
  secondButton.offsetWidth = secondButton .offsetWidth;
  secondButton.classList.add("bounce");
}
```

I updated the code snippet.

Comment: You are making the same button bounce onclick. I want a different button to bounce when a button is clicked. Something like "when you click on button A, Button B should bounce".

Comment: @ShellZero I updated my answer for you. How is that?

Comment: It works only for the first time. But thanks for the tip. It seems like there is an error in the line 3 of the javascript.

Comment: @ShellZero I solved both those issues and updated my answer. Is that what you were looking for or did I misunderstand you?